# im getting [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNFusedLocation.getCurrentPosition')] when using react-native-geolocation-service

Tags: reactjs, react-native, geolocation

Tried using react-native-geolocation-service and i followed the setup provided but still getting the error.
im using:

- react-native": "0.63.4,
- react-native-geolocation-service": "^5.2.0

```
import Geolocation from 'react-native-geolocation-service';

         Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
              console.log(position);
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error.code, error.message);
            },
            {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 10000, maximumAge: 100000},
          );
```

Answer (score 3):

I think its my fault, i fixed it by rebuilding

```
cd android
./gradlew clean
./gradlew cleanBuildCache
cd ../
```

thanks for the answers

Answer (score 3):

In android/build.gradle:

Add this line =>playServicesLocationVersion = "21.0.1" inside buildscript

In android/app/build.gradle:

Add this line or upgrade the version to 21.0.1 if the older version already exists=>

implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

I am Brazilian and therefore I speak Portuguese, but I will use the translator to try to help you.

What you can do is the following:

The `getCurrentPosition` method is giving an error and this error probably doesn't have `.code` or `.message`. I suggest giving a `console.log (error)` before trying to get your information.

Comment: i still get the same error, i read that it might be a setup problem but i followed the procedure in their setup